# Running Python Scripts in Azure

Tags: python, azure, cron

I have a GitHub repository with some .py scripts. What would be the steps to follow to get them running in Azure through a cron scheduler?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/functions/ & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

Comment: @Manakin Is this OS dependent? The Azure I'm referring to is has Linux running on it. Also, is it possible at all to link it to my repository?

Comment: What do you mean by Azure, the portal or a virtual machine? a function is a _severless_ app - meaning you don't need to provision any specific hardware for it, you just need to deploy your code and then it can run and you pay for your compute on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use [Azure Python Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser) with a [time trigger binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python) and call your Python modules from there.

A simplistic sample project structure could look like this

```
├── function-app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── function.json
└── shared/
    └── your_module.py
```

where `__init__.py` contains the Azure Function wrapper code that gets executed according to the cron schedule

```
from __app__.shared.your_module import your_function

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    # call your_function() here
```

and `function.json` contains among others the cron schedule expression, in this example running every 6 hours.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 */6 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is there any way I could read the latest version of my .py from my GitHub repository?

Comment: You could create a Github Action that gets triggered every time you push changes in your repository. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-github-actions?tabs=python